# Transition Animation not Triggered Automatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I am having an issue getting transition animations to run.
As far as I understand, such transitions are triggered automatically.
However, I cannot see any animation when I try them in the simulator or local machine.

For instance, this is just showing the button, with no entrance animation whatsoever:

```
<Button Content="Transitioning Button">
     <Button.Transitions>
         <TransitionCollection> 
             <EntranceThemeTransition/>
         </TransitionCollection>
     </Button.Transitions>
 </Button>
```

I also tried other scenarios listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452703.aspx
but none of them seems to be working.

Storyboard animations are running without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set FromVerticalOffset or FromHorizontalOffset to get it working.

Code:

```
<Button Content="Transitioning Button">
                <Button.Transitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="100" />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Button.Transitions>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Just tried it out, but still no animation is triggered.